# how to use useRef to reference latest value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

People use useRef to save latest value like this code

```
function MyComponent({ value }) {
  const valueRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    valueRef.current = value;
  });
}
```

I know useEffect needs for concurrent mode.

and useEffect is executed in the order of the definition

```
function MyComponent({ value }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log1');
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log2');
  });
}
// result is
// log1
// log2
```

so in the below code,
log1 is printed with old value and log2 is printed with new value

```
function MyComponent({ value }) {
  const valueRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log1', valueRef.current);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    valueRef.current = value;
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log2', valueRef.current);
  });
}
```

I think it's weird because the value is different according to the position.

What is the right way to use useRef to reference latest value?
(FYI I know it's better to use deps than to use useRef)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken the `useEffect` hook is run in order it's applied if additional conditions are not set (the dependencies param, the second param of `useEffect` hook).
In your case, the hook is setting a new value in the the second invokation.

Comment: Those `useEffect` hooks, without dependencies, are equivalent to just logging a value, mutating it, and logging it again. This is essentially the idiomatic way to cache *a* previous value for use on the next render, the idea being to get the current ref value (from the prev render cycle) and cache a value (for the next render cycle), but not mutating the ref during the cycle like you've done. So common that react actually provides a [recipe](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state).

Comment: If you concern about the ordering of `useEffect` may give you previous value instead of latest value, you may update the ref in `useLayoutEffect` instead, as it is invoked before `useEffect` due to it being synchronous. However I don't know if this'll be guaranteed in the future or not.

Comment: @SonDang OP would see the same output with `useLayoutEffect`. It isn't a matter of when the hook is called (i.e. before first paint, or after), but rather the order they are called. OP is essentially logging a pre & post value within the current render cycle.

Comment: @SonDang thanks I think `useLayoutEffect ` would be one of the solutions.

Answer (score 17):

It really depends on what you mean by latest value, your code does store latest value to `valueRef.current`.

```
  const valueRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log1', valueRef.current);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    valueRef.current = value;
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log2', valueRef.current);
  });
```

If you do want to have a more "stable" value, then you should use `setState`.

```
  const valueRef = useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(1)
    console.log('log1', valueRef.current);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // value is still 1
    valueRef.current = value;
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    // value is still 1
    console.log('log2', valueRef.current);
  });
```

IMHO, `useRef` is a very difficult topic, it was designed for `Dom` ref initially. But then people find it useful when it comes to decouple the variable from the rendering state/prop. You can't actually say `useRef` always store the latest value, it actually still store the regular value, except it won't trigger re-render, since the reference to this `ref` is fixed after initialization (only `ref.current` is changing).

Answer (score 4):

Another approach is change ref value after if condition.

```js
  const valueRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log1', valueRef.current);
  });
  if(valueRef.current !== value) {
    valueRef.current = value;
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('log2', valueRef.current);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way is to store *some* "current" value for the next render and retrieve the current ref value (the previous value). [Hooks FAQ: How to get the previous props or state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state)

```
const prevValueRef = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
  prevValueRef.current = value; // cache current value for next render
});
const prevValue = prevValueRef.current; // get previous value from last render
```

Running sandbox demo

[image: Edit useRef-previous-value]

Comment: I know the usePrevious hook but my question is how to use latest value in useEffect.
when a value is changed too much, we can use useRef like [react-docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often)
`latestProps.current = props` part of the docs

Comment: @landvibe I'm not sure I follow, why would the value change at all? When you say "latest" what do you mean? "current" value, or "previous" value?

Comment: the value means effect dependency. as you can see, the title of the docs is `What can I do if my effect dependencies change too often?`

Comment: I guess I still don't see what that has to do with the topic here, accessing a previous value. This particular pattern doesn't specify a dependency array so the effect is triggered *on each render* to cache a current value for each *next render*. What is the concern? Are you asking how to use the stored previous value?

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest value from all code positions (render, `useEffect` body, disposal function body), you have to use at least two `useRef`s.

Here is the code

```
export const usePrevRef = value => {
    const currentRef = useRef()
    const prevPref = useRef()
    prevPref.current = currentRef.current
    currentRef.current = value
    return prevPref
}
```

[image]

If you use one `useRef`, and place the `ref.current = value` update in ③(or⑤), then the value won't be correct if called from ④and⑥(or⑥).

I wrote a [blog](https://transang.me/perfect-last-value-hook-in-react/) on this. Please feel free to check.